Session management in spring-oauth2-authorization-server
I am developing an application that consists of a gateway as a oauth2-client and an authorization server. I do not quite understand, based on what information, the session timeout for these services should be selected. The thing is that the access time to the client session is updated with each request to it, while the session of the authorization server is not updated (since, except for authorization, it is not accessed) and expires exactly after the specified timeout. Is there a way to make the authorization server session not expire until it expires on the client?
I want that if a user is using the application and his session is active on the client, it also remains active on the authorization server.

I think connecting the client to the auth server in this way would uncommon. What have you tried so far?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@SteveRiesenberg Ok, as far as I understood from your answer, the end of the session on the authorization server should not affect the functionality of the client. This is exactly what I wanted to know, sorry for the incorrect question. I had a problem with an expired refresh token, when the session on the client is still valid, but on the authorization server it has already expired. But now I update the refresh token together with the access token and this problem is solved, since the refresh token cannot expire if the session is still valid. Thank you.

Glad you got it solved. Thanks for the update.
